# JQuery calculator data-numbers aren't working | Getting the allclear button to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**How do i get the AC button to work to remove everything and the del btn**
I am trying to make a calcuulator from scratch using Jquery, however, I have been struggling to get the calculate to work.

I have tried messing around with javascript and jquery and trying to learn event handlers, however, I have had no success.

```js
function removeNumbers() {
    $(".current-operand").innerHTML = ' ';
}



$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
    $(".data-number").click(passInt);
    $(".data-allclear").click(removeNumbers);
}

function passInt() {
    $('.current-operand').append(parseInt($(this).html()));
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
        <div class="previous-operand"></div>
        <div class="current-operand">0</div>
    </div>
    <button class="span-two data-allclear">AC</button>
    <button class="data-delete">DEL</button>
    <button class="data-operation">+</button>
    <button class="data-number">1</button>
    <button class="data-number">2</button>
    <button class="data-number">3</button>
    <button class="data-operation">*</button>
    <button class="data-number">4</button>
    <button class="data-number">5</button>
    <button class="data-number">6</button>
    <button class="data-operation">+</button>
    <button class="data-number">7</button>
    <button class="data-number">8</button>
    <button class="data-number">9</button>
    <button class="data-operation">-</button>
    <button class="data-number">.</button>
    <button class="data-number">0</button>
    <button class="span-two data-equals">=</button>
</div>

</main>
```

On clicking the buttons with the class data-number. An alert should pop up.
My ultimate goal is fo rthose numbers to turn up on screen

Comment: I am not trying to get anything loaded on the window.onload but i need the event to occur when the button is clicked

Comment: If you will update your answer each time and won't looking at answers below - you won't never get an answer and it's a minimum what could be happen to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In this way it works well

```js
$(()=>{
  $('.data-number').click(function(){
      alert('hi');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
        <div class="previous-operand"></div>
        <div class="current-operand">0</div>
    </div>
    <button class="span-two data-allclear">AC</button>
    <button class="data-delete">DEL</button>
    <button class="data-operation">+</button>
    <button class="data-number">1</button>
    <button class="data-number">2</button>
    <button class="data-number">3</button>
    <button class="data-operation">*</button>
    <button class="data-number">4</button>
    <button class="data-number">5</button>
    <button class="data-number">6</button>
    <button class="data-operation">+</button>
    <button class="data-number">7</button>
    <button class="data-number">8</button>
    <button class="data-number">9</button>
    <button class="data-operation">-</button>
    <button class="data-number">.</button>
    <button class="data-number">0</button>
    <button class="span-two data-equals">=</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $(".data-number").click(function(){
    if ($('.current-operand').html()=='0') $('.current-operand').html('');
      $('.current-operand').append(parseInt($(this).html()));
  })
  
  $(".data-operation").click(function(){
      $('.previous-operand').html($(this).html());
  });
  
  $(".data-allclear").click(function(){
      $('.current-operand').html('0');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
        <div class="previous-operand"></div>
        <div class="current-operand">0</div>
    </div>
    <button class="span-two data-allclear">AC</button>
    <button class="data-delete">DEL</button>
    <button class="data-operation">+</button>
    <button class="data-number">1</button>
    <button class="data-number">2</button>
    <button class="data-number">3</button>
    <button class="data-operation">*</button>
    <button class="data-number">4</button>
    <button class="data-number">5</button>
    <button class="data-number">6</button>
    <button class="data-operation">+</button>
    <button class="data-number">7</button>
    <button class="data-number">8</button>
    <button class="data-number">9</button>
    <button class="data-operation">-</button>
    <button class="data-number">.</button>
    <button class="data-number">0</button>
    <button class="span-two data-equals">=</button>
</div>

</main>
```

sure you can get the number on the button

Comment: Hi, 
I tried using your code to make my own variation on it, however, how would I get the all clear button to work. Can you please view my code.